# How to wait for a JFrame to close before continuing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jdialog, cardlayout

My program consists of 3 main 'sections'. Main function, Login form and App form. The main function should do something like: Open Login form, wait for it to close, then open App form. I can't get the waiting part to work, or rather, I don't know how I would go around doing that.

I was told by someone to use a JDialog instead and use `setModal(true)`, but with that approach the Login form wouldn't appear on the taskbar, which is terrible in my opinion.

Another thing I considered was to open the App from inside the Login after it closes, but that feels like bad design since that'd make the Login form non-reusable.

So, please, what would you suggest?

Comment: Why must the login appear on the task bar, since the main app will be there, and you don't want more than one task bar item for an individual program. Your best option is to use a modal JDialog.

Comment: I dispose of the Login after it closes, so there's always just one at a time.

Comment: It may not be "fun" for the user to have a bunch of windows thrown at them. Check out CardLayout.

Comment: I've already started using MigLayout. Thought the layout was irrelevant.

Comment: Your misunderstanding the point. CardLayout is not a layout in the usual sense. Please check the tutorial out. I've added a link to the tut in my answer.

Comment: So basically the moment a user presses 'Login' and it logs him in, instead of closing the window it just takes the 'login' panel out (fortunately I do have a separate panel), resizes the frame and pops the App frame in?

Comment: That seems fine for this, but I feel like I won't be able to use that every time :(

Comment: You could show the main GUI first, but not let it be "activated" until the login dialog has been successfully complete. Any way, up to you as you have several options that you can choose from.

Comment: See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Why must the login appear on the task bar, since the main app will be there, and you don't want more than one task bar item for an individual program. Your best option may be to use a modal JDialog.
- Another option is to use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to swap "views".
- A third option is to use a JFrame if you must but attach a listener to it, a WindowListener I believe, to respond to its close event.
- Regardless of which route you go, your login gui should be a JPanel so that you can place it anywhere you wish and then change your mind later.