# How to make JFrame pause thread similar to how JOptionPane works

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, joptionpane

I am making a game and whenever the player comes in contact with an enemy, I want a `JFrame` to pop up asking if you want to fight the enemy, but when the `JFrame` pops up, the game keeps running in the background. I noticed with `JOptionPanes`, the thread pauses until the `JOptionPane` is gone. How would i get a similar effect with a `JFrame`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait for a JFrame to close before continuing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335733/how-to-wait-for-a-jframe-to-close-before-continuing)

Comment: *"..the game keeps running in the background. I noticed with JOptionPanes, the thread pauses until the JOptionPane is gone."*  That is entirely wrong.  The **user** is blocked from accessing the main UI, but any animation (if done correctly) keeps animating away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: don't use a JFrame -- You're asking for a window that acts as a modal dialog -- so ***use*** a modal dialog, a JDialog to be exact. Note that this is exactly what JOptionPane does.

Comment: Can i still do the same thing that JFrames do? Such as card layouts, buttons, etc.

Comment: @RyanHosford: it can do all of those things. Understand that just like a JFrame, it is a top-level window. It can't create another icon on your icon bar. And closing it cannot automatically close the application (unless you write code specifically to do this).